# My Autodesk is not going away

Tags: windows-10

I am not sure if I am asking in the right site. I have an issue with this application.

I have completely uninstalled my Autodesk on my computer through the control panel. But it is still there on the toolbar whenever I turn on my computer. The app is gone but I am not sure why is still there on my toolbar. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: How exactly are you determining Autodesk still exists on your system?

Comment: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/customer-service/download-install/remove-products/remove-windows-products and https://knowledge.autodesk.com/customer-service/download-install/remove-products/clean-uninstall

Answer (score 0):

The app is still there on your toolbar as an unused application shortcut. That doesn't mean it still exists. Simply remove it from the toolbar.

How I know: This has happened every time I uninstall an application. It left its shortcuts behind (toolbar, desktop) but that didn't mean the app was still there. You can just delete the shortcut from wherever without worry

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. Yes, I delete it everytime. But when I turn on my computer again, it pops up again in my toolbar. I can not track the app location nor in the control panel since I have uninstalled it.